# How to convert yaml to csv file format?

Tags: bash, text-processing, csv

I need to write bash script which takes yaml file:

```
first:John
last:Smith

first:David
last:Bennet
```

and convert it to csv file:

```
John,Smith
David,Bennet
```

Any ideas?
Thanks!

Comment: this is not a valid yaml content. You should have it in this way https://pastebin.com/KEffBae3

Answer (score 1):

You will find a complete library for it and you can easily use it, YAML2CSV...
see github , here is the link provided.
https://github.com/tokland/yaml2csv

Comment: Can you provide an example of the library in addition to the link you provided?

Comment: How do we install and use this from a terminal window?

Answer (score 1):

Here is an `awk` command:

```
awk -v RS="first:|last:" '{gsub("first:|last:","",$0);print $1","$2}' RS='' infile.txt
```

Output is as you are expecting:

```
John,Smith
David,Bennet
```

Answer (score 1):

Using sed and Miller (https://github.com/johnkerl/miller) and running:

```
<input.yaml sed -r 's/:/ /g' | mlr --x2c -N cat >output.csv
```

you will have

```
John,Smith
David,Bennet
```

Please note: your input file is not a valid yaml.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `sed` command to do this conversion :

```
 <file.yaml sed 's/first://g' | sed ':a;N;$!ba;s/\nlast:/,/g' | sed -r '/^\s*$/d' > file.csv
```

Explanation :

- `<file.yaml` is the input file (here, your YAML file to convert)
- `sed 's/first://g'` would remove each `first:` string list character
- `sed ':a;N;$!ba;s/\nlast:/,/g'` do almost same thing as previous command, but all options are used to detect newlines character which are previous `last: string character lists (and replace that with a comma`,`); see this [StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1252191/9670273) more further details
- `sed -r '/^\s*$/d'` would remove each empty lines left, see this [StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16414489/9670273) for more details
- `> file.csv` would redirect result into a new `.csv` file (if this file didn't exist, it would be created automatically), as conversion is finished

Result :

```
John,Smith
David,Bennet
```

---

Create your own script which will able to convert any `.yaml` file to `.csv` file. In my example, my script is named `YAMLtoCSV.sh` :

```
#! /bin/bash

if [ ${1#*.} = "yaml" ]
then
    <$1 sed 's/first://g' | sed ':a;N;$!ba;s/\nlast:/,/g' | sed -r '/^\s*$/d' > ${1%%.*}.csv
    echo "Conversion from" $1 "to" ${1%%.*}.csv "done"
else
    echo "This file didn't have YAML extension"
fi
```

and to execute it (don't forget to make the script executable with the command `sudo chmod +x YAMLtoCSV.sh`) :

```
./YAMLtoCSV.sh /home/<user>/file.yaml
```

You would get a file named `file.csv` next to your `.yaml` file, so his path is `/home/<user>/file.csv`

Note that I added an `if` statement in order to prevent file conversion error (which won't destroy any data, but would create some useless other data)